# Access Upsize to Sqlserver not transfer data

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, ms-access, data-transfer

I have a Access Database with 11,000,000 records.I want to transfer this records to same table in Sqlserver 2008 using Upsize tools. This tool creates the database and tables correctly but the table  in SQL Server is empty and data is not transferred.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't mention receiving an error message, check the field types in the new SQL Server table to confirm they are compatible with their Access counterparts.

If it looks OK, start Access and create an ODBC link to the SQL Server table.  Then create an Access "append query" to add data from the Access table to the SQL Server table.

```
INSERT INTO remote_table (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM local_table
WHERE date_field >= #2012-01-01# AND date_field < #2012-02-01#;
```

Note I imagined a `WHERE` clause which limits the number of rows to a reasonably small subset of the 11 million rows.  Adjust as needed for your situation.

If that `INSERT` succeeds, repeat it with different `WHERE` conditions to append chunks of the data to SQL Server until you get it all transferred.

And if it fails, hopefully you will get an error message which explains why.

Comment: How to "create an ODBC link to the SQL Server table" and "append query"?

Comment: Create a DSN for you SQL Server database.  In Access 2007, choose "External Data", choose "ODBC Database" from the "More" dropdown.  Then choose the Link radio button on the "Get External Data" dialog, choose your DSN in the "Select Data Source" dialog, and finally choose your SQL Server table from the "Import Objects" dialog.

Comment: For the append query, start with a new Access query using the local table as it's data source.  Select the fields you wish to upload to the server, then change the query type to "Append", and select your linked table as the destination.

Answer (score 1):

As noted here in most cases it is a bad date or simply a date that is outside of SQL server that cases a fail.  I would suggest you use the Access migration tool as opposed to the built in tool. It does a MUCH better job.

You find this utility here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28763

The above tends to deal with the date and other issues that prevent data uploads far better than the built in upsize tool